# How to show polyhedral cone of nonnegative vectors contains finitely generated cone?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $P=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax \geq b, x \geq 0 \}$ be a nonempty polyhedron for matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

According to Minkowski-Weyl theorem $P$ can be written as

$$
P=\text{conv}(v_1,\cdots,v_p)+ \text{cone}(d_1,\cdots,d_l)
$$
for some $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $d_j \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $C=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax \geq 0, x \geq 0 \}$.

Show that $\text{cone}(d_1,\cdots,d_l) \subseteq C$.

The thing that that I cannot cope with is how to connect the finite number $l$ that can be any natural number with dimension of the matrix $A$.

I tried the following:

Let $z \in \text{cone}(d_1,\cdots,d_l)$, so there exist non-negative $\mu_i$'s such that

$$
z= \sum_{i=1}^l \mu_id_i
$$
where $\mu_1,\mu_2,\cdots,\mu_l \geq 0$.

We can write $z$ as the following:

$$
z=
\begin{bmatrix}
d_1 & d_2 & \cdots & d_l
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_1 \\
 \mu_2 \\
 \cdots \\
 \mu_l
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, we should come up with an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ for which we have $Az \geq 0$ and $z \geq 0$ to prove the claim. But the problem is we do not have $z \geq 0$ necessarily.

Comment: The statement is not true for any choice of $v_i$, so you need to chose them appropriately.

Comment: @ LinAlg: The statement is true because it says for some $v_i$ and $d_j$. Also, it does not say what $p$ and $l$ are. Maybe I am wrong who am using wrong number for $l$.

Comment: a proof by contradiction is easier here: what if $z$ is not in $C$?

Comment: @LinAlg: How we can do that?

Comment: if $z$ does not satisfy $Az\geq 0$ or $z\geq 0$, moving in the direction of $z$ will violate a constraint of $P$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $P$ can be written as 
$$
P=\operatorname{conv}(v_1,\cdots,v_p)+ \operatorname{cone}(d_1,\cdots,d_l)=V+D.
$$
The set $D$ is a cone, hence, for every $v\in V$ and $d\in D$ we have that $v+td\in P$, $\forall t\ge 0$. That is
$$
A(v+td)\ge b,\quad v+td\ge 0,\quad\forall t\ge 0.
$$
Now divide by $t$ and let $t\to +\infty$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{t}Av+Ad\ge\frac{1}{t}b\quad&\Rightarrow\quad Ad\ge 0,\\
\frac{1}{t}v+d\ge 0 \quad&\Rightarrow\quad d\ge 0.
\end{align}
Therefore, every $d\in D$ belongs to $C$.

Comment: Could you help me show the reverse? I mean $ C \subseteq  \text{cone}(d_1,\cdots,d_l) $. It cannot be immediately observed from your proof to show the reverse, I am having trouble of producing $x \geq 0$?

Comment: I have proved it using different method, but you might be show it differently. I posted it as an another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3041877/how-to-show-directly-that-finitely-generated-cone-contains-polyhedral-cone-of-no